# PHP: separate a string based on `|` delimiters

Tags: php, string, filter, character

I am trying to figure out a way using *PHP* that I can parse a string of data from a *URL* to separate each entry based on the character `|`.  Example data:

> 66.85.14.212:7254|108.174.48.186:8340|72.46.152.194:15240|162.248.91.125:7266|91.121.83.48:7619|185.153.228.114:5775|

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [explode()](http://php.net/explode) function to split the string and remove empty elements with [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$string = '66.85.14.212:7254|108.174.48.186:8340|72.46.152.194:15240|162.248.91.125:7266|91.121.83.48:7619|185.153.228.114:5775|';
$ips = array_filter(explode('|', $string));
```

which results in an array containing all your ip adresses

```
Array
(
    [0] => 66.85.14.212:7254
    [1] => 108.174.48.186:8340
    [2] => 72.46.152.194:15240
    [3] => 162.248.91.125:7266
    [4] => 91.121.83.48:7619
    [5] => 185.153.228.114:5775
)
```

There are also two other functions, [split()](http://php.net/split) and [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split) which supports regular expressions too.

Comment: And if you do `array_filter(explode('|', $string));` it'll remove that last empty array element for you.

Comment: Its not printing the array.

Comment: lol. The result you see down there is the structure of the array you create when you use explode. To print it like that use [`print_r($ips);`](http://php.net/print_r)